# How to reduce the value of VRAM and memory

Tags: rendering

I recently bought a new computer with a 3060Ti card. When I started making a big scene for myself, I found that when rendering, the blender would automatically close. I checked and found that the value here is too big.[image] Is there any way to lower these two numbers without reducing the effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some of the options in the simplify section in the render properties.

[image]

Also if your scene contains many repeating objects, make sure they are instances. You can create an instance by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, instead of the usual <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> when duplicating.